# Understanding the first Line from inside angular v2.0.0.0-alpha.22.ts (Lists vs Arrays)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, ecmascript-6

I have some free time right now and decided to look at [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

Inside of the `typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts` file on `line 11`:

```
interface List<T> extends Array<T> {}
```

I understand there is a lot going on in this line:

- [interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces)
- List
- [Generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics)
- [Extend](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-extending-interfaces)

### **Question:**

> What is the difference between List and Array through the lens of javascript/ts?
>
> When should I consider using Lists vs Arrays?
>
> What would be an example of using a List vs an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between List and Array through the lens of javascript/ts?

None.

> When should I consider using Lists vs Arrays?

Use array. List is just an optional naming (effectively an alias).

> What would be an example of using a List vs an Array?

Generally just use `Array`.

Comment: Lol, Fair enough THanks for the answer.